# when the user chooses to stop,how print the number of user wins, losses, and ties

Tags: java

At that point, the program reveals both choices and prints a statement indicating if the user won, the computer won,or if it was a tie.Continue playing until the user chooses to stop,then print the number of user wins, losses, and ties.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MAX = 3;
        int randomNumber;
        int userChoice;
        int computerChoice;
        int choice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();//random number generated by computer

        String str, another = "y";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rounds = 0;
        userChoice = 0;

            while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {// allows y or Y
                System.out.print("enter 1= rock 2= paper 3 = scissor(0 to quit):");
                rounds++;
                userChoice = input.nextInt();
                computerChoice = rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
                System.out.println("computer picked " + computerChoice);

                int lose = 0;
                int win = 0;
                int tie = 0;
                int computerScore = 0, userScore = 0;


                if (userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2 || userChoice == 3) {
                    if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
                        System.out.println("Tie Game!");
                        System.out.println();
                        tie++;
                        //rounds++;
                    } else if (userChoice == 1) {

                        if (computerChoice == 2) {
                            //rock is covered by paper
                            System.out.println("  you lose");
                            lose++;
                            computerScore++;
                            //rounds++;
                        } else if (computerChoice == 3) {
                            //rock smashes scissors
                            System.out.println("  you win");
                            win++;
                            userScore++;
                            //rounds++;
                        }
                    } else if (userChoice == 2) {
                        if (computerChoice == 3) {
                            //paper is cut by scissors
                            System.out.println("  you lose");
                            lose++;
                            computerScore++;
                            //rounds++;
                        } else if (computerChoice == 1) {
                            //paper covers rock
                            System.out.println("  you win");
                            win++;
                            userScore++;
                            //rounds++;
                        }
                    } else if (userChoice == 3) {

                        if (computerChoice == 1) {
                            //scissors are smashed by rock
                            System.out.println("  you lose");
                            lose++;
                            computerScore++;
                            //rounds++;
                        } else if (computerChoice == 2) {
                            //scissors cut paper
                            System.out.println("  you win");
                            win++;
                            userScore++;
                            //rounds++;
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("invalid number");
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("User wins: " + win + " User loses: " + lose + "User ties " + tie);
                System.out.print("Do you want to play again (y/n)? ");
                another = scan.nextLine();
            }
           }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the inner loop wrapped with a `while(true)`?

Comment: yes you are right I delete it and works fine but still I don't know how to print the number of user wins, losses, and ties

Comment: I highly recommend you learn to use [Switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: I will learn Switch next week.

Comment: @EddieB Your web page looks very bad in my browser. I do not use default font size, I use font size 18.

Comment: @KorayTugay Yeah well that's kinda of an edge case no?

Comment: @EddieB I think a lot of people increase font size at least slightly.

Comment: @KorayTugay I think most people just zoom. Not change the default browser font size.

Comment: @EddieB well ok, it is your page and you are the boss. but I rarely see problems in web pages.. just wanted to inform you. have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the following code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
```

public class RockPaperScissor {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MAX = 3;
    int randomNumber = 0;
    int userChoice = 0;
    int computerChoice = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    int rounds = 0;
    int lose = 0;
    int win = 0;
    int tie = 0;
    int computerScore = 0;
    int userScore = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();//random number generated by computer
    String str, another = "y";

    userChoice = 0;

    while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {// allows y or Y
        System.out.print("enter 1= rock 2= paper 3 = scissor(0 to quit):");
        rounds++;
        userChoice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        if(userChoice == 0){
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again (y/n)? ");
            another = input.nextLine();
        } else if (userChoice > 0 && userChoice < 4){
            computerChoice = rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
            System.out.println("computer picked " + computerChoice);

            if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
                System.out.println("Tie Game!");
                System.out.println();
                tie++;
            } else if (userChoice == 1) {

                if (computerChoice == 2) {
                    //rock is covered by paper
                    System.out.println("  you lose");
                    lose++;
                    computerScore++;
                } else if (computerChoice == 3) {
                    //rock smashes scissors
                    System.out.println("  you win");
                    win++;
                    userScore++;
                }
            } else if (userChoice == 2) {
                if (computerChoice == 3) {
                    //paper is cut by scissors
                    System.out.println("  you lose");
                    lose++;
                    computerScore++;
                } else if (computerChoice == 1) {
                    //paper covers rock
                    System.out.println("  you win");
                    win++;
                    userScore++;
                }
            } else if (userChoice == 3) {

                if (computerChoice == 1) {
                    //scissors are smashed by rock
                    System.out.println("  you lose");
                    lose++;
                    computerScore++;
                } else if (computerChoice == 2) {
                    //scissors cut paper
                    System.out.println("  you win");
                    win++;
                    userScore++;
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("invalid number");
        }
        System.out.println("computer score: " + computerScore + " You Score: " + userScore + " Rounds: " + rounds+"\n");
    }
 }
```

}

I had remove scan and one while loop from your original code and define the existing condition.

Good Luck !!!

Comment: ohhh thanks but still the userScore and Computer score is not showing

Comment: I had change the score showing statement. Please check the code changers and try it. If it is worked fine please vote up the answer and  mark as the correct

Comment: the part that has to show the result is not working correctly

Comment: Thanks how can you make this line appear just at the end not everytime we play.

Comment: System.out.println("computer score: " + computerScore + " You Score: " + userScore + " Rounds: " + rounds+"\n");
    }

Comment: Thnx and best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Your program seems fine, except for these points:

- indentation is important!
- you have a `while(true) { /* do stuff */ break; }` that is pointless.
- `scan` and `input` are redundant. you may use any of them to read all user input.

  - they're equal, both of them are `Scanner.new(System.in)`

Comment: I would add that the `while(true)` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: I have scan to read yes for playing again and input to read the number of choices

Comment: Updated the answer. but you can use `input.nextLine()` to read the yes from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You are infinite loop without Boolean condition

Firstly declare a field Boolean flag and put its initial value to false then when you will start game then set flag value to true and run while loop untill flag is true when you want to stop then simply set flag to false